# PHP Iterate through a MySQL result a certain amount of times

Tags: php, arrays, json, mysqli

At the moment I have this code looping through the whole results of a query:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$data = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 

    $name      = $row ['name'];
    $desc      = $row ['description'];
    $cat       = $row ['category'];
    $price     = $row ['price'];
    $quantity  = $row ['quantity'];
    $id        = $row ['productID'];
    $image     = $row ['image'];

    $arr = array();

    $arr ["id"] = $id;
    $arr ["name"] = $name;
    $arr ["desc"] = $desc;
    $arr ["cat"] = $cat;
    $arr ["price"] = $price;
    $arr ["quantity"] = $quantity;
    $arr ["image"] = $image;

    array_push($data, $arr);

}
echo json_encode($data);
```

I want to change this to only loop through a set amount of results. I have a variable further up the code called `$amount` which is the amount of results I would like.

I hear I should use `mysql_result()` and a for loop to count to `$amount`, but I'm not sure how my existing code will work with that set up! Suggestions please.

EDIT:

@Styphon Pointed out that I don't actually need to change my iteration code for this to be solved. Just needed to add a `LIMIT` to my SQL query.

Comment: Why not just add a limit to your query? And why do you put row into a var and then var into array then push into data?

Comment: I haven't had much experience with MySQL, how would this be done? Sounds like it could work though!

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html look for LIMIT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql = "rest of query...
LIMIT $amount"; //This will limit it to whatever is $amount. Just make sure to have it on the end of your query.
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$data = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 

    $arr = array();
    $arr["id"] = $row['productID'];
    $arr["name"] = $row['name'];
    $arr["desc"] = $row['description'];
    $arr["cat"] = $row['category'];
    $arr["price"] = $row['price'];
    $arr["quantity"] = $row['quantity'];
    $arr["image"] = $row['image'];

    array_push($data, $arr);

}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: OP stated that there is a variable called `$amount` that reflects the number of results to be processed. So you want `LIMIT $amount"; as your last line in the query, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is the same whether you use mysql_ or mysqli_ (but you should use mysqli or even pdo). It goes something along this lines:

```
$num = 0;
$amount = 10;

while ($f = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
  // your code;
  $num++;
  if ($num==$amount) break;
}
```

As you mentioned for loops, with for loop you might do something like this

```
for ($i=0;$i<$amount;$i++) {
  $f = mysql_fetch_array($q);
  //your code
}
```

Obviously you should adjust it to suit your needs.

Comment: But obviously, you should use LIMIT, I thought you were aware of this before.

Comment: Upvoting as "the answer to the question as asked": _I hear I need to use a for loop and count to $amount_ - this shows (albeit with a `while`) how that would be done. Useful information for future visitors - although (as you point out) this is not the best solution.

Comment: Now that you mention it, mysql_fetch_* do move an internal pointer ahead, so simple for loop could be simpler. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: How does your new formulation work when the number of results is less than `$amount`…? You could do `for($i=0; $i<$amount && $f = mysql_fetch_array($q); $i++) {` but it starts getting ugly, fast.

Comment: Yes, I thought of that, but I wrote it anyway. He should figure some stuff out for himself :) He could also break from loop when there is nothing fetched, there are options, it's up to the one who asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
LIMIT 0, $amount
```

This will limit your result to $amount.

Comment: so `LIMIT 0, $amount` just goes on the end of my query?

Comment: Well, that was much easier than I thought it was going to be! Thank you!